# Intel NUC is having black screen after updating to Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS from 20.04.5

Tags: 22.04, intel-graphics, intel-nuc

I updated the GRUB and reinstalled the ubuntu-desktop but still did not fix it.

```
lotus@lotus:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
lotus@lotus:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake UHD Graphics (rev 04)

lotus@lotus:~$ lshw -c video
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Comet Lake UHD Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:6022000000-6022ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.

GRUB File as below
lotus@lotus-robotics:~$ lshw -c video
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Comet Lake UHD Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:6022000000-6022ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
lotus@lotus:~$ cat /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: You have "nomodeset" and "nouveau.[...]"? Why if you don't have a nvidia card? That just breaks the Intel driver.

Comment: I don't have an NVIDIA graphics card. It is a Comet Lake UHD Graphics, vendor: Intel Corporation in my IntelNUC

Comment: What is the output of `lsmod | grep i9`. Did you select an X11 session or a Wayland session?

Comment: lotus@lotus-robotics:~$ lsmod | grep i9
i915                 3117056  7
ttm                    86016  1 i915

drm_kms_helper        311296  1 i915
cec                    61440  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm                   622592  8 drm_kms_helper,i915,ttm
video                  65536  1 i915

Comment: I had Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS installed earlier in Dualboots. I upgraded to 22.04.3 LTS

Comment: So your GPU driver is now loaded (and you should see a change in lspci). Let's try testing your graphics: `sudo apt install weston`. Then type `weston` at a TTY (CTRL+ALT+BACKSPACE to exit). Are you able to see the Weston wallpaper?

Comment: after installing the weston,I got a popup screen named "Weston Compositor  screen0". I still don't see any image while boot up or even the Grub menu.

Comment: $ lspci -knn | grep -iEA5 'vga|3d|display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake UHD Graphics [8086:9bca] (rev 04)
        DeviceName:  GPU
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Comet Lake UHD Graphics [8086:2081]
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model [8086:1911]

Answer (score 1):

You have options that conflict with your current setup. Reset them to the default by doing the following:

1. `sudo vim /etc/default/grub` and delete change these two lines from

```bash
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"
```

to

```bash
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

2. `sudo update-grub`
3. `reboot`

You don't have a Nvidia GPU, so "nouveau.modeset" is irrelevant. "nomodeset" is actively harmful because it prevents the Intel driver from loading. Having a GPU driver enabled might be more important on 22.04 than 20.04 because newer Ubuntu versions use Wayland. Wayland is tightly integrated with the GPU drivers.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just tried it but unfortunately, it did not bring the graphical view yet.